# yahoo messenger sdk

Tags: sdk, yahoo-messenger

I've set my mind on writing a plugin for yahoo messenger, but I can't find a sdk anyware , and from the information I gathered it seems that the sdk has been removed by yahoo. Is there a way I could accomplish this ?

thankyou !

Comment: Yep, they've dropped support for plugins:

http://developer.yahoo.net/forum/index.php?showtopic=2027

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find what you need within the open source yahoo client [Gyachi](http://gyachi.sourceforge.net/)